# Create MS Access query with matching columns similar to Index-Match?

Tags: ms-access

Let's say I have 2 tables

**Table 1**

| PersonID | PersonName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Ann |
| 2 | Bob |
| 3 | Charles |

**Table 2**

| ItemID | PersonID-1 | PersonID-2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |

I want to create a query from table 2 that matches the PersonName from table 1:

| ItemID | PersonName-1 | PersonName-2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ann | Bob |
| 2 | Charles | Ann |

If it's only 1 column then I can create a merge query but when it's 2 columns or more i dont know how. In Excel this can easily be done with Index-Match. I'm new to Access so if anyone can guide my I'm very thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a query with this SQL:

```sql
SELECT I.ItemID, P1.PersonName AS [PersonName-1], P2.PersonName AS [PersonName-2]
FROM
    ItemTable I
    INNER JOIN PersonTable P1 ON I.[PersonID-1] = P1.PersonID
    INNER JOIN PersonTable P2 ON I.[PersonID-2] = P2.PersonID
ORDER BY I.ItemID
```

Note that it is easier to work with column names being valid identifiers, i.e., names consisting only of alphanumeric characters and underscores and not starting with a digit. Examples: `PersonName_1`, `PersonName1`, `Person_ID`. Because then you will not have to enclose the names in square brackets.

If you write a column name as `I.PersonID-1`, Access thinks it must subtract `1` from a column named `I.PersonID`.